# Does parallel requests with RXJS will do better to performance?

Tags: angular, performance, rxjs

Problem: I need to download huge file (5-10gb) with simple XHR requests, to simplify a question I need to do at-least: 100 requests (could be more).
I would like to improve the performance to it using RXJS (parallel http-requests).

The questions:

1. Is it at all possible to improve the performance with Parallel?
2. Does parallelizing the requests won't be the same as using 1 request for each iteration of the request-loop? The bandwidth is the same - NO?
3. Is there other ways to improve my perf?

Stack:

- Angular 7.2.x
- Typescript 3.2.4
- Rxjs 6.4.0

What I actually reached for:
What I actually need is to apply sync on `mergeMap` to trigger it on/off for example I have 100urls but I do not wish em to run until the last one of them.

For example I want it to run up until the 17th but will pause making requests and wait for certain logic and request to finish.

Code Example:

```
from(observableQueries)
           .pipe(
               mergeMap(partialQuery => this.messageService.getResults(partialQuery, true), 4),
               takeWhile(o => {
                   if (!o.isMoreResults && o.auditMessageList.length === 0) {
                       this.logger.log(`First page that returns false ${ o.number }`);
                       this.logger.log(`Count of responses that exists in array: ${ allResults.length }`);
                       if (!firstPageThatShouldBeStopped) {
                           firstPageThatShouldBeStopped = o.number;
                       }

                       if (allResults.length === firstPageThatShouldBeStopped) {
                           return false;
                       }
                   }
                   return true;
               }),
               retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy()),
               catchError((err, caught) => {
                   this._alertService.error(this._translate.instant('EXPORT_TO_CSV_DOWNLOAD_ERROR'));
                   return throwError(err);
               })
           )
           .subscribe(
               (res: MessagesResult) => {
                   if (reThrowError) {
                       this.logger.info('Error will be thrown for e2e purposes');
                       throw new Error('Error will throw for e2e purposes');
                   }
                   if (res.isMoreResults && res.auditMessageList.length > 0) {
                       allResults[res.number] = res;
                       this.subject.next(true);
                   } else if (!res.isMoreResults && res.auditMessageList.length > 0) {
                       allResults[res.number] = res;
                       this.subject.next(true);
                   } else {
                       this.subject.next(false);
                   }
               },
               err => {
                   // clear subject after emitting value...
                   this.subject.next(true);
                   return this.handleError(err);
               },
               () => {
                   this.logger.info('Download file finished...');
                   this.logger.info('Time consumed: ', performance.now() - start);
                   try {
                       this.logger.info(`Count Responses: ${ allResults.length } `);
                       const allResultSorted = this._sortResults(allResults);
                       let counter = 0;
                       for (let i = 0; i < allResultSorted.length; i++) {
                           this.logger.info('Index: ' + i, allResultSorted[i]);
                           counter += allResultSorted[i].auditMessageList.length;
                           this.logger.info('Length OF Messages: ' + i, counter);
                           this.fileSaver.save(!allResultSorted[i].isMoreResults, allResultSorted[i].auditMessageList,
                               `audit-events_${ LOCAL_QUERY_COPY.application }_${ timestamp }_${ moment()
                                   .tz(this._timezoneService.timezone).zoneName() }.csv`, null, headers);
                       }
                       this.subject.next(false);
                   } catch (e) {
                       this._alertService.error(this._translate.instant('EXPORT_TO_CSV_DOWNLOAD_ERROR'));
                       return this.handleError(e);
                   } finally {
                       // clear subject after emitting value...
                       this.subject.next(true);
                   }
               }
           );
```

The code works! But the issue is with redundant calls. How it would be possible to make em stop up until the last requests are finished running.

Comment: You might be blocking the main thread. To avoid that use a Web worker

Comment: Just a random thought: the parallelization of a process might be best suited by a control scheme in which the client and server continue to agree on their best connection / concurrency. If the server cannot handle more concurrent requests, it should not allow more, and the client should stop getting more concurrency when the bandwidth or processing power no longer supports it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes for sure only if your server is capable of handling your desired concurrency
2. 1 request for each iteration of the request-loop is sequential request after one and other so it is not the same as parallelizing
3. Normally if you have 100 request we will limit the concurrency to a number server won't hang on excessive requests, demonstrate at the code below

```js
     const urls=[url1,url2,url3]
     const concurrency=5
     const fetchUrls=urls.map(url=>defer(_=>fetch(url)))
     merge(...fetchUrls,concurrency).subscribe(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does parallelizing the requests won't be the same as using 1 request for each iteration of the request-loop? The bandwidth is the same - NO

=> I would say NO, because, on the server, when one thread is executing the first request, the second tread can download the second request
=> For me, it's better to parallelize, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Do you have a code example of how to parallelize the stuff without knowing the amount of href's before the execution?

Comment: I just made another answer in Order to add code in it.

Comment: @davidr, it would be better to update your existing answer and add this there. There is no reason to have multiple answers in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RXJS 'merge' operator:
Assuming that getData(url) is the methode making the request and that this methode return an Observable, you can do:

```
const urls: string[] = {url1, url2, url3,...};
let mergeHttpCallObservalbe: Observable<any>;
urls.forEach((url: string) => {
  const newHttpCallObservalbe : Observable<any> = myService.getData(url);
  if (mergeHttpCallObservalbe){
    mergeHttpCallObservalbe = merge(mergeHttpCallObservalbe, newHttpCallObservalbe);
  } else {
    mergeHttpCallObservalbe = newHttpCallObservalbe;
  }
});

// Now you have merged all your Observable, you can subscribe:
mergeHttpCallObservalbe.subscribe(result => {
  // Do your stuff...
});
```

Here is a good article regarding Rxjs Operators: https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511

Hope it will helps

Comment: and what if I have 100 urls and I need to do pairs or triplets of these? To make all the requests. I'm actually aggregating data for a huge file (That being downloaded via AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, yes parallelism should improve matters, up to a point.

A quick google of "browser request limits" turns up the [following](http://SD&final_price=16000&is_recurring=false&payment_method=stripe&purchased=330917&purchased_at=1560744479&purchased_course_id=182325&purchased_list_price=16000&sale_id=29691911&tax_charge=0&user_id=24045185), which shows that you can make between 2 and 13 concurrent requests per domain, depending on the browser. As long as the user's internet connection isn't saturated, and you haven't hit that limit yet, you should indeed be able to make and await requests concurrently. It will be faster than making your requests one at a time, since the browser won't actually have to do any work while it waits for the next one.

The bandwidth is indeed the same, but the throughput is higher.

What will improve your performance depends on your particular situation, but I would guess that making 100 small requests is actually slower than making a single large one, since each small request has to accomplish a separate handshake before it can start receiving data.

As far as RxJs, I like [Fan Cheung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553969/870178), but I see you have a retry mechanism, which their answer does not. It should be easy enough to add retry to each of the "fetch" calls, or to keep a list of the failed urls, and try them again after the first batch has been attempted. Again, it depends on your particular circumstance.

What exactly do you mean by redundant calls? What behavior would you like to see that you are not seeing?

Comment: can you instead edit your original question with a screen shot or something?

Comment: I can try to explain. I have a limit of 100 requests, but I don't want to get there if for example it has finished on the 12-request. But because the data-result is big(10k) array size, it's actually continue to make more "BLANK" requests and stops working on the 42nd-request. How can - "freeze" the `mergeMap` to make redundant calls?

Comment: also this is suddenly a very different question from “does parallelism improve performance”

Comment: 1 url with diff queryparams

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195208/discussion-between-maus-and-iamstalker).